# Display Data on Screen after Form Submission using Solspace Freeform Pro

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

With Freeform, I know that when the user submits a form entry, you can set up an email notification that sends all the data they entered to them in an email message. Is it possible to also have their information display on screen after they submit?

Email is just not as dependable as it once was, so I'm trying to have a backup "Print this page now for your records" type of option - just in case the notification email gets lost.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by using `%%entry_id%%` in your `return=""` parameter in `{exp:freeform:form}`: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#return

`%%entry_id%%` will be replaced by the created entry_id when the form was submitted. After form submission, the entry_id would be a segment in the URL (eg. `/form/thank-you/123`).

From there, you can retrieve your Freeform entry by using `{exp:freeform:entries}` and display your submitted data on screen.

Comment: Hi Solspace, I've implemented a 'thank you'-page this way (with a listing of data we've received). But this feels very unsafe. If someone just tries entering a different entry_id in the url, they can see all the private data from that user... This cannot be the way to go. Do you have a better solution for this? I've tried encoding/decoding the %%entry_id%%, but it doesn't get parsed (I suspect a conflict between plugins).

Comment: How about using `{if freeform:author_id == member_id} ... {/if}`, or `{if '{freeform:author_id}' == member_id}` inside your `{exp:freeform:entries}` tag? You could also compare current_time with entry_time and not show the data if the entry is older than X seconds/minutes/hours. Probably a few other inventive ways around that.

Comment: nice! As Solpace suggested, I was planning on putting an author check in place to avoid this issue. Thanks guys.

Comment: People don't need to login/register to fill in a contact-form so the comparison of time seems the best option.